# Sharepoint 2010: Display List Rows differently, depending on the content

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-2010

I want to display a sharepoint list in such a way that rows are displayed with different content, based on the value of some field.

For example, if a row is a "Company", then I want to display the name of the company, the address, etc. Also, this row should be shaded and displayed in bold. 
If the row is a "Person", then I want to display the name, e-mail, Job description, etc.

**Question: Would that be possible by manipulating the XSLT templates?**

In fact, I want to create some sort of "switch"-statement in each field, which populates the field dynamically, depending on data in another column.

I'm asking beforehand, because it seems that it would be quite a lot of work to go in depth with the XSLT topic. (The code generated in Sharepoint Deisgner is about 10.000 lines long ...)

My intention is to create a compact, printer-friendly report.
We have already tried the grouping function of lsits, but that is not sufficient for our task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible with XSLT.  I imagine that your XSLT has a template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Row">
  <!-- XSLT for generating row -->
</xsl:template>
```

You should be able to override this template by adding your own that are more specific. Assuming that **Type** is the name of the column that you will use to determine the row type:

```
<xsl:template match="Row[@Type = 'Company']">
  <tr>
    <!-- Content for a company row -->
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row[@Type = 'Person']">
  <tr>
    <!-- Content for a company row -->
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

An approach like this should theoretically work, but it would be necessary to see some of your XSLT to be sure. Perhaps you could upload it to someplace like PasteBin?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that helped me a lot for better understanding the structure of a sharepoint view. I'm currently working on this. If you are interested, here is a pastebin of the row template. I'll try to remove the <xls:for each> template, and replave it with some code for the fields I want. http://pastebin.com/2Re66vJ7